# Split routes in Sinatra with private methods?

Tags: ruby, oop, design-patterns, sinatra

I want to do these:

1. Use rails-like `user_params` to specify allowed keys to be updated.
2. Split routes like http://sinatrarb.com/extensions.html.

The code below works, but leaks `user_params` to other files. How can I keep `user_params` private?

```rb
# app/routes/reset_passwords.rb
 module MyApp
   module Routes 
     module ResetPasswords 
       class << self 
         def registered(app) 
           app.patch '/reset_passwords' do

            # ...

            if @user.update(Routes::ResetPasswords.user_params(params))
              status 204
            end
          end

        def user_params(params)
          params.fetch('user', {}).slice('password')
        end
```

```rb
# app.rb
module MyApp
  class App < Sinatra::Base
    register Routes::ResetPasswords
    register Another::Modules
  end
end
```

**EDIT1**

As @tukan suggests, the code below works well if `MyApp` registers only one extension. However, on adding another extension which has a method named `user_params`, it is overridden by the new `user_params`.

```
# app/routes/reset_passwords.rb
 module MyApp
   module Routes 
     module ResetPasswords 
       class << self 
         def registered(app) 
           app.patch '/reset_passwords' do

            # ...

            if @user.update(user_params(params))
              status 204
            end
          end

        private
        def user_params(params)
          params.fetch('user', {}).slice('password')
        end
```

Comment: I'll pass this question to someone more knowledgeable about the Sinatra extensions.  I've read thethe tutorial you linked and I think your code needs more fixing and I want you to get a proper answer.

Comment: What do you mean by **adding another extension with user_params**

Comment: I clarified it as adding another extension **which has a method named user_params**